# Fluid - Get Pagetitle in Link

Tags: typo3, fluid

i need the Pagetitle from the actual Page in an Link. Like this:
index.php?var=Pagetitle.

But how can do this?

This is my Code

```
<f:link.page pageUid="{field.link}" additionalParams="{title}">Further Informations</f:link.page>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the [VHS Viewhelper](http://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Page/InfoViewHelper.html) you can do something like this:

```
<f:link.page pageUid="123" additionalParams="{title : {vhs:page.info(pageUid : 123, field: 'title')}}">
    Additional Information
</f:link.page>
```

Mind you the title will not be urlencoded..